# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^{n^2}}{b^{cn}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's consider the series
$$s=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^{n^2}}{b^{cn}}$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ ($\mathbb{C}^*$) and $c\in \mathbb{Z},c\neq 0$.

Which one would be a good approach to find the values of convergence of $s$?

I mean, I can consider the cases where $|a|>1$, where $|a|=1$, and $|a|<1$ (Each of these cases gets some subcases for conditions on $b$ and $c$), but it's too long an approach.

I think the convergence is mainly dependent on the value of $a$, and I think there should be a better way to check it.

Comment: What does $\mathbb C^*$ denote?

Comment: @Math1000 It denotes $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

Comment: Three cases depending on the modulus of a number is far from the worst case scenario I've seen. Does the ratio and root tests leave something to be desired?

Comment: Effectively, using the root test makes it easier. Thanks.

Comment: Intuition: for large $n$, $a^{n^2}$ will be freaking huge for $a > 1$ (or incredibly tiny for $a < 1$) compared to $b^{cn}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**
$$
\frac{a^{n^2}}{b^{cn}}=\left(\frac{a^n}{b^c}\right)^n
$$
thus your series converges if and only if $|a|^n<|b^c|=|e^{c\log b}|=|b|^c$ definitely, and this could happen iff $|a|<1$, for every $b$ and $c$ or if $|a|=1$ when $|b|^c>1$.

Comment: Thanks. Using the root test I could get to that result.